# When condition in ansible

Tags: linux, automation, ansible

I have written the following playbook and it's working fine but when I am doing the same thing with roles, when condition of the fail module is messing up. Irrespective of the values defined, when I am giving > in when, in fail module, it's skipping and when giving < , it's failing.
Please don't mind the syntax and '-' s, it's messing up here.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars: 
    vmcpu_list:
      - vmcpu: 2
      - vmcpu: 1
      - vmcpu: 1
    vcpu_value: 0 

  tasks:
    - set_fact: 
          vcpu_value: "{{ vcpu_value }} + vmcpu_list[{{item}}].vmcpu"
      with_sequence: start=0 end="{{ vmcpu_list | length -1 }}" 
    - debug:
           var: "{{ vcpu_value }}"
    - fail: 
          msg: " provided vcpu are more"
      when: vcpu_value|int > 5
```

NOTE: Sorry earlier I have given vcpu_value|int > 5 above but it should be vcpu_value|int > 3

Answer (score 0):

```
 - fail: 
          msg: " provided vcpu are more"
      when: vcpu_value|int > 5
```

you have set vcpu_value: 0 
condition assessement vcpu_value < 5 it dosn't match your condition ==> ansible will skip the task

```
   - fail: 
              msg: " provided vcpu are more"
          when: vcpu_value|int < 5
```

you have set vcpu_value: 0 
condition assessement vcpu_value < 5  OK ==>  ansible will get execute the task

There is no problem your code works fine no strange behavior  ^^

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I have increased the vcpu_value to 4 in tasks. So is it going to take the changed value or is it going to consider the value mentioned in the vars??    And vcpu_value|int > 3 not vcpu_value|int > 5.